# Add ItemsControl items directly to parent

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, bing-maps, itemscontrol

I'm working on an application that uses the WPF Bing Maps library.  The `DataContext` of the map control I'm working on has a list of GPS coordinates (`Location` objects), each of which should be represented by a `Pushpin` element on the map.  I was hoping to add these pushpins to the map through XAML, using an `ItemsControl` (simplified for brevity):

```
<m:Map>
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GPSCoordinates}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <m:Pushpin Location="{Binding}">
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</m:Map>
```

This doesn't work, however, because the `Pushpin` elements don't get added directly to the `Map` element; rather, they are encapsulated by the `ItemsControl`'s `ItemsPanel` and the `ItemsControl` element itself.  **Is there a way to generate a list of items and have the items defined in the `DataTemplate` added directly to the `ItemsControl`'s parent?**

In other words, I'd like the Visual Tree to look like this:

```
<m:Map>
  <m:Pushpin />
  <m:Pushpin />
    ...
</m:Map>
```

instead of this:

```
<m:Map>
  <ItemsControl>
    <StackPanel>
      <m:Pushpin />
      <m:Pushpin />
        ...
    </StackPanel>
  </ItemsControl>
</m:Map>
```

Comment: I don't think its possible in pure XAML. You should find a way to add the Pushpins to the Children property of Map. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh709044.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it does not add Pushpins as direct children of the Map control, [`MapItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.mapitemscontrol.aspx) is what you are looking for:

```
<m:Map ...>
    <m:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GPSCoordinates}">
        <m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <m:Pushpin Location="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </m:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </m:MapItemsControl>
</m:Map>
```